# Problems in DrawerNavigator in React-Native with react-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I'm trying to implement a Drawer Navigator in my application but it returns this error.

I'm using React-Native and react-navigation and android 9.0 for emulator

Error Message:
[App return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6LEH.jpg)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScroollView,
  Dimensions,
  Image
} from "react-native";
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  DrawerItems,
  SafeAreaView[enter image description here][3]
} from "react-navigation";

import LoginScreen from "./Screens/Login/LoginScreen";
import HomeScreen from "./Screens/Home/HomeScreen";

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return <Apps />;
  }
}

const CustomDrawerComponent = props => (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View
      style={{
        height: 150,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
      }}
    >
      <Image
        source={require("./images/perfil.png")}
        style={{ height: 120, width: 120, borderRadius: 60 }}
      />
    </View>
    <ScroollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </ScroollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
);

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Settings: LoginScreen
  },
  {
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent
  }
);
const Apps = createAppContainer(AppDrawerNavigator);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

I expected that application to start with the side menu working.

Comment: which version of react-navigation are you using

Comment: There's a typo in your code? It's`ScrollView` not `ScroollView`.

Comment: Hello @RajeshBhartia, i'm using a react-navigation 3.0

Comment: @NishantNair LOL That's the problem! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

THe problem is in my code. It's `ScrollView` not `ScroollView`, my bad xd